# Как с помощью регулярного выражения вставить после 5 ссылки текст?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно на 10 html сайтах вставить ссылку после 5 закрывающего тега ссылки "`</a>`", собираюсь делать замену с помощью скрипта замены текста. Мне сказали что такое возможно с помощью регулярного выражения. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать с помощью регулярки?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ATBJNK/1

Comment: Вы хотите заменить существующее значение?

Comment: нет, добавить после него текст

Comment: спасибо огромное но мне нужно 1 раз вставить ссылку

Comment: @Alex
Вы можете использовать функцию preg_replace();
Example:
$text = 'Hello';
echo preg_replace("/$/", '  world.', $text);

Comment: https://ideone.com/JSZXQx